# SSH connection timeout after a couple of seconds when my second interface is up

Tags: ssh, networking, pfsense

So I'm so lost on what to do to debug right now. I've spent a couple of weeks on this issue without understanding what is happening.

I'm trying to have the ssh server to only work with connections from the admin subnet but this shouldn't stop routed traffic from any subnet to the admin subnet.

So here is the setup. I have a VM under debian 9. This VM has two interfaces, eth0 in on the user subnet and eth1 is on the admin subnet. Both subnets have a DHCP/DNS server which is pfsense. Hostnames are automatically added to the DNS.

My sshd config file is the default on, with root login disabled and `ListenAddress` set to eth1 IP.

So far this is the behavior that I have seen:

Both interface up, `ListenAddress` enabled:

- ssh from the user network through the pfsense router: connection
  established, can act for a short amount of time then the terminal
  freezes and times out. On wireshark I have some TCP retransmissions
  at this time
- ssh from the admin network directly: Everything works
- ssh from a computer with both network: Everything works
- ssh from a 3rd network (with rule to forbid access to the user network): Everything works

Both interfaces up, `ListenAddress` disabled :

- Everything works, but of course ssh is available through the user
  network interface

Interface eth0 down, `ListenAddress` enabled:

- Everything works

There isn't any firewall on the server on purpose. I use the IP address to ssh and not the hostname, but both have the same result no matter if both interfaces have the same or a different hostname.

I really don't know where the issue is coming from.
For me it can't be the pfsense because right now it simply allows all network traffic from the user network to go to the admin network. But maybe i'm wrong.
And no error in the sshd logs either.

Comment: Your question does not really explain what your problem is. Are you trying to forbid ssh connections from the user network? Please explain what you are trying to achieve, and how it is not working.

Comment: @Johan-Myréen i'm just trying to ssh into my server. but the connection drop out when my client can access the 2 interface of the server and i don't know why

Comment: @JohanMyréen You don't even have to read the question; even the title does explain that...

Comment: @VlycopDoo Still unclear to me. You say you can ssh the server from the admin network, "Everything work". So what *is* the problem? Is it that you get a "connection established" from the user network, even though you shouldn't?

Comment: @JohanMyréen no i should be abble to connect because i my network stream is rerouted into the admin network. the issue is that the terminal froze and time out for no apparent reason

Comment: Does SSH work from the pfsense router over the user network?

Comment: You did a wireshark on the client side, good. What does a wireshark/tshark/tcpdump show you on the server side?

Comment: If the server is supposed to be reachable from both networks, why do you listen specifically on the admin network address instead of any address?

Comment: @HaukeLaging it seam to work, i plug my kvm in the pfsense and right now i have ssh into a server on the user network and the connection stay up

Comment: @xhienne don't have a x11 on the server and didn't know any wireshark alternative, i will try to do a tcpdump

Comment: At least you will confirm my answer by spying what comes and goes through each interface. PS: tshark is wireshark's text mode. You can also record what those tools are spying, download the recordings on your computer and examine them with wireshark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the TCP packets sent by your server use another path than the TCP packets you send to it, and your pfsense then thinks the connection is not established and removes it from its table of established connections, subsequently rejecting any incoming packets.

The TCP packets that go from your machine on the user network to your server are sent to the pfsense router which forwards them to your ssh server. Since your ssh server has an interface on your user network, the return packets are sent directly to your machine through its interface on the user network. Consequently, pfsense only sees the packets going from your machine to the server, and since the first TCP SYN frames have not been ACKnowledged, it then decides that the connection is dead after some time and drops subsequent packets.

A quick workaround on the pfsense would be to SNAT the ssh packets going from the user network to the admin network. Thus the ssh server would use the pfsense for its return path. The ssh server would then be unable to know the actual source address of course.

A better approach is to use source based routing. See [this question](https://superuser.com/q/376667/669855) for example.

Comment: Sounds good but as I understand it both interfaces are connected to the router and the source address of the reply packets should be the same as the target address.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I believe it is the same actually. That's just that the packets use the shortest path, which is the interface to the user network.

Comment: Wow. That good thinking. i will check if it's really that in a moment, but i'm a bit shook that the packet don't follow the same root as the incoming one.

Comment: @xhienne i can confirm with a tcpdump -i any that the server ack the syn but because it simply use the ip, the shorts route is through the eth0 ... i will have to search how to fix that without nating, because i will have issue with other stuff i'm sure

Comment: @VlycopDoo Classic routing use the destination address to chose the outgoing interface. You must use policy routing on the source address of outgoing packets. See my last edit.

Comment: Thank you @xhienne, for your reply and for your correction of my question. i'm not English but when i see all my mistake i think i could have done better ...

Comment: @VlycopDoo Do not worry about this. This site is open to everyone but English is a prerequisite, that's why we don't expect every question to be written in perfect English.

Comment: @VlycopDoo there is never any guarantee that return packets will follow the same route in reverse as the original packets followed.  each host (and each hop in the route path) sends packets by what it determines to be the best route and that may lead to wildly different return paths (and on multi-hop paths like large networks or the internet, wildly different paths that fluctuate as intermediate hops go up or down or change in metric)